# Remove JSON element

Tags: javascript, json

I want to remove JSON element or one whole row from JSON.

I have following JSON string:

```
{
   "result":[
       {
           "FirstName": "Test1",
           "LastName":  "User",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "user",
           "LastName":  "user",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "Ropbert",
           "LastName":  "Jones",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "hitesh",
           "LastName":  "prajapti",
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: i think you still got some json errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a JSON attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219630/remove-a-json-attribute)

Comment: I answered the question, you might want to have a look at it. I added the answer because many people don't take into consideration how garbage collection works.

Comment: @ChrisF - not a duplicate since delete will create an "undefined" item in the array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912150/deleteing-json-object-from-an-array-creates-undefined-objects

Answer (score 239, accepted):

```
var json = { ... };
var key = "foo";
delete json[key]; // Removes json.foo from the dictionary.
```

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements from an array.

Comment: Why are always the worst answers at the top?  Could it possibly be the rep points?  I searched. I found. You had the correct answer.

Comment: I don't get this answer.  Where's "foo" in the test data?

Comment: Where's foo in the test data? Well, the first line is actually pseudocode. Instead of json = {...}, it would be something like json = {foo: 'value'}

Comment: delete json[key]; ? How many "FirstName" in given example?

Wrong answer.

Comment: The question (at the time of answering) was ambiguous and did not ask for a particular key of an object or row of the array to be removed. The answer I have given provides sufficient information to solve this homework problem.

Comment: using *delete* will leave a null element in the array

Answer (score 31):

Do NOT have trailing commas in your OBJECT (JSON is a string notation)

*UPDATE*: you need to use [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) and not delete if you want to remove items from the array in the object. Alternatively filter the array for undefined after removing

```js
var data = {
  "result": [{
    "FirstName": "Test1",
    "LastName": "User"
  }, {
    "FirstName": "user",
    "LastName": "user"
  }]
}
console.log(data.result);
console.log("------------ deleting -------------");
delete data.result[1];
console.log(data.result); // note the "undefined" in the array.


data = {
  "result": [{
    "FirstName": "Test1",
    "LastName": "User"
  }, {
    "FirstName": "user",
    "LastName": "user"
  }]
}

console.log(data.result);
console.log("------------ slicing -------------");
var deletedItem = data.result.splice(1,1);
console.log(data.result); // here no problem with undefined.
```

Answer (score 20):

You can try to delete the JSON as follows:

```
var bleh = {first: '1', second: '2', third:'3'}

alert(bleh.first);

delete bleh.first;

alert(bleh.first);
```

Alternatively, you can also pass in the index to delete an attribute:

```
delete bleh[1];
```

However, to understand some of the repercussions of using deletes, have a look [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Answer (score 18):

For those of you who came here looking for **how to remove an object from an array based on object value:**

```js
let users = [{name: "Ben"},{name: "Tim"},{name: "Harry"}];

let usersWithoutTim = users.filter(user => user.name !== "Tim");

// The old fashioned way:

for (let [i, user] of users.entries()) {
  if (user.name === "Tim") {
    users.splice(i, 1); // Tim is now removed from "users"
  }
}
```

**Note:** These functions will remove all users named Tim from the array.

Comment: Upvoted, but this fails if there are multiple Tims in the user list.  You'll need to loop backwards to avoid messing up the array indices during the removal step.

Comment: I agree @TawabWakil Good point :)

Comment: users.splice(users.findIndex(user => user.name === "Tim"), 1)

Answer (score 13):

I recommend `splice` method to remove an object from JSON objects array.

```
jQuery(json).each(function (index){
        if(json[index].FirstName == "Test1"){
            json.splice(index,1); // This will remove the object that first name equals to Test1
            return false; // This will stop the execution of jQuery each loop.
        }
});
```

I use this because when I use `delete` method, I get `null` object after I do `JSON.stringify(json)`

Comment: Splice should be the accepted answer, delete replaces the json document with a NULL insertion.... I wanted delete to delete it -- splice will.

Answer (score 8):

All the answers are great, and it will do what you ask it too, but I believe the best way to delete this, and the best way for the garbage collector (if you are running node.js) is like this:

```
var json = { <your_imported_json_here> };
var key = "somekey";
json[key] = null;
delete json[key];
```

This way the garbage collector for `node.js` will know that `json['somekey']` is no longer required, and will delete it.

Comment: I've read about doing it this way too, but I cannot get this to work. It still leaves the null references

Answer (score 7):

1. Fix the errors in the JSON: http://jsonlint.com/
2. Parse the JSON (since you have tagged the question with JavaScript, use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))
3. [Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete) the property from the object you created
4. Stringify the object back to JSON.

Comment: Drat - you answered while I was removing commas :(

Answer (score 6):

As described by @mplungjan, I though it was right. Then right away I click the up rate button. But by following it, I finally got an error.

```
<script>
var data = {"result":[
  {"FirstName":"Test1","LastName":"User","Email":"test@test.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"sk","Country":"canada","Status":"False","iUserID":"23"},
  {"FirstName":"user","LastName":"user","Email":"u@u.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"Gujarat","Country":"India","Status":"True","iUserID":"41"},
  {"FirstName":"Ropbert","LastName":"Jones","Email":"Robert@gmail.com","City":"NewYork","State":"gfg","Country":"fgdfgdfg","Status":"True","iUserID":"48"},
  {"FirstName":"hitesh","LastName":"prajapti","Email":"h.prajapati@zzz.com","City":"","State":"","Country":"","Status":"True","iUserID":"78"}
  ]
}
alert(data.result)
delete data.result[3]
alert(data.result)
</script>
```

Delete is just remove the data, but the 'place' is still there as *undefined*.

I did this and it works like a charm :

```
data.result.splice(2,1);
```

meaning : delete 1 item at position 3 ( because array is counted form 0, then item at no 3 is counted as no 2  )

Answer (score 5):

Try this following

```
var myJSONObject ={"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"};
console.log(myJSONObject);
console.log(myJSONObject.ircEvent);
delete myJSONObject.ircEvent 
delete myJSONObject.regex 
console.log(myJSONObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

if we want to remove one attribute say "firstName" from the array
we can use map function along with delete as mentioned above

```
   var result= [
       {
           "FirstName": "Test1",
           "LastName":  "User",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "user",
           "LastName":  "user",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "Ropbert",
           "LastName":  "Jones",
       },
       {
           "FirstName": "hitesh",
           "LastName":  "prajapti",
       }
   ]

result.map( el=>{
    delete el["FirstName"]
})
console.log("OUT",result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly use filter? Say you wanted to remove ***all*** instances of Ropbert

```
let result = [
   {
       "FirstName": "Test1",
       "LastName":  "User",
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "user",
       "LastName":  "user",
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "Ropbert",
       "LastName":  "Jones",
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "hitesh",
       "LastName":  "prajapti",
   }
   ]

result = result.filter(val => val.FirstName !== "Ropbert")

(result now contains)

[
   {
       "FirstName": "Test1",
       "LastName":  "User",
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "user",
       "LastName":  "user",
   },
   {
       "FirstName": "hitesh",
       "LastName":  "prajapti",
   }
   ]
```

You can add further values to narrow down the items you remove, for example if you want to remove on first **and** last name then you could do this:

```
result = result.filter(val => !(val.FirstName === "Ropbert" && val.LastName === "Jones"))
```

Although as noted, if you have 4 'Ropbert Jones' in your array, ***all*** 4 instances would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
json = $.grep(newcurrPayment.paymentTypeInsert, function (el, idx) { return el.FirstName == "Test1" }, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A descent Solution is here
My JSON array is

```
const [myData, setData] = useState([{username:'faisalamin', share:20}, {username:'john', share:80}])
```

I want to delete john on a button click in renderItem or in .map

```
const _deleteItem = (item) => {
                    const newData = myData.filter(value => { return value.username !== item.username });
                    setData(newData);
            }
```