# angularJS how to manipulate resolve returm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using AngularJS and RESTAngularJS.
My resolve return correct JSON. for example "subject"

```
0: {subjectId: "1", subjectCode: null, subjectLongName: "English", subjectShortName: "English"}
1: {subjectId: "2", subjectCode: null, subjectLongName: "Hindi", subjectShortName: "Hindi"}
2: {subjectId: "3", subjectCode: null, subjectLongName: "Maths", subjectShortName: "Maths"}
3: {subjectId: "4", subjectCode: null, subjectLongName: "Physics", subjectShortName: "Physics"}
4: {subjectId: "5", subjectCode: null, subjectLongName: "Chemistry", subjectShortName: "Chemistry"}
```

when I am assigning to, as below

```
$scope.SecondItems = subject; 
console.log($scope.SecondItems);
```

I am getting result as following

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, route: "subject", reqParams: null, restangularized: true, fromServer: true, parentResource: null…]


{
  "subjectId":"3",
  "subjectCode":null,
  "subjectLongName":"Maths",
  "subjectShortName":"Maths",
  "subjectDescription":null,
  "route":"subject",
  "reqParams":null,
  "restangularized":true,
  "fromServer":true,
  "parentResource":null,
  "restangularCollection":false,
  "IsSelected":true
}
```

How get rid of extra fields like

```
 "reqParams":null,
 "restangularized":true,
 "fromServer":true, 
 "parentResource":null,
 "restangularCollection":false,
```

OR what wrong I am doing?

Comment: You can use lodash: reject. https://lodash.com/docs#reject

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310304/remove-json-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the plain method from restangular to get rid of them.

Like: 
`$scope.SecondItems.plain();`

See https://github.com/mgonto/restangular