# How to keep only wanted fields in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have

```
const eva = {name: "Eva", age: 3, hobby: "dance", state: "NY"};
const ann = {name: "Ann", age: 9, hobby: "read", state: "WA", schoolyear: 3};
```

I want to have a trim function, which only keeps the fields I want.

```
const fields = ["name", "age", "state"]
```

and the output will be

```
const eva2 = {name: "Eva", age: 3, state: "NY"};
const ann2 = {name: "Ann", age: 9, state: "WA"};
```

I can't iterate through all fields and delete fields inside the loop. That will end the loop earlier.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove json element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310304/remove-json-element)

Comment: It's not duplicated. I don't know the specific fields that I want to delete. I can't iterate through key because that will end the loop earlier.

Comment: just delete it? `delete eva.hobby`?

Comment: Then either your question isn't clear (at least to me) or you misunderstand the referenced question / answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delete to delete an key from an object. Create a function which will accept an object from where the keys will be delete. Now inside that function do `Object.keys` which will create an array of all the keys of the object.Then iterate this array and use `indexOf` to check if this item is present in the main array. If not then use `delete` operator to delete the key from the object

```js
const eva = {
  name: "Eva",
  age: 3,
  hobby: "dance",
  state: "NY"
};
const ann = {
  name: "Ann",
  age: 9,
  hobby: "read",
  state: "WA",
  schoolyear: 3
};


const fields = ["name", "age", "state"];

function delKey(obj) {
  let objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
  objKeys.forEach(function(item) {
    if (fields.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      delete obj[item]
    }
  })
  return obj
}
console.log(delKey(eva))
console.log(delKey(ann))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the delete function, here is a quick example:

```js
const eva = {name: "Eva", age: 3, hobby: "dance", state: "NY"};
const ann = {name: "Ann", age: 9, hobby: "read", state: "WA", schoolyear: 3};
const fields = ["name", "age", "state"]
// get the keys in the object
var keys = Object.keys(eva);
// loop over all the keys
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
  // check if it's in the array of fields to keep 
  if (fields.indexOf(keys[i]) < 0)
     // delete the property because it isnt in fields
     delete eva[keys[i]];

console.log(eva);
```

Comment: This gives me ""Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier""

Comment: @YixingLiu yeah, it was because const was misspelt in the OP and it carried over to my example, i've fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more concisely using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const eva = { name: "Eva", age: 3, hobby: "dance", state: "NY" };
const allowedKeys = ['name', 'age', 'state'];

const newObject = Object.keys(eva).reduce(function(newObj, key) {
    if (allowedKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        newObj[key] = eva[key];
    }
    return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

also you if you want default values to
shape your object.

```js
function getShapedValue(shape, defaultValue) {
    const shaped = {};

    for(const key of Object.keys(shape)) {
        if(defaultValue.hasOwnProperty(key))
            shaped[key] = defaultValue[key]
        else
            shaped[key] = shape[key]
    }

    return shaped;
}


const shape = { name: "", age: null }

const userNameAge = getShapedValue(shape, fullUserObject)
```