# Remove JSON parent element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently trying to code an application with javascript. It pulls data from a database and the response I'm getting is something like that:

```
    {
       "values":[
           {
               "name": "Munich",
               "location": "Germany",
               "native_lang": "German",
           },
           {
               "name": "London",
               "location": "England",
               "native_lang": "English",
           },
           {
               "name": "Rome",
               "location": "Italy",
               "native_lang": "Italian",
           }
       ]
    }
```

But I need to have the JSON like that:

```
    [
       {
           "name": "Munich",
           "location": "Germany",
           "native_lang": "German",
       },
       {
           "name": "London",
           "location": "England",
           "native_lang": "English",
       },
       {
           "name": "Rome",
           "location": "Italy",
           "native_lang": "Italian",
       }
    ]
```

How can I delete the parent `values` object in my JSON?

Comment: That's not valid. If it's an array, it needs `[]` around it.

Comment: @Barmar This is JavaScript. It does not distinguish between object property access and array index access. You would only need `[]` when either
* The property name is not a valid identifier
* Or, the property name is a value of an expression

Comment: @DMaster I don't know what you're talking about. My comment was made before someone edited the question to put the objects in an array.

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

Just access the `values` property like a JavaScript object.

**LONG ANSWER:**

You didn't post the JavaScript code snippet so it's quite difficult to give you an appropriate answer.

Assuming you have the following code:

```js
const jsonString = getDataFromTheDB()
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject) // still has the "values" layer
const values = jsonObject.values // what you want, without the "values" layer

// BONUS: Just in case you want to convert the object back to a JSON string but without the "values" layer
const valuesJSON = JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310304/remove-json-element/39753601) :

just do this (consider `json` the variable that contains your json):

```js
var key = "values";
var results = json[key];
delete json[key];
json = results;
```

`console.log(json)` will output the following:

```
 [
           {
               "name": "Munich",
               "location": "Germany",
               "native_lang": "German",
           },
           {
               "name": "London",
               "location": "England",
               "native_lang": "English",
           },
           {
               "name": "Rome",
               "location": "Italy",
               "native_lang": "Italian",
           }
]
```

But you dont even have to do the last 2 steps of the code snippet above, you could also just directly use `results` variable and have the same output by `console.log(results)`.

Answer (score -1):

You could take the object and create a new variable with just the array.

```js
var vals = 
{
   "values":[
       {
           "name": "Munich",
           "location": "Germany",
           "native_lang": "German",
       },
       {
           "name": "London",
           "location": "England",
           "native_lang": "English",
       },
       {
           "name": "Rome",
           "location": "Italy",
           "native_lang": "Italian",
       }
   ]
}

var arr = vals.values;

console.log(arr);
```